# ListBox SelectedItem edit from another form

Tags: c#, winforms

I tried below code. First I select a listbox item and then I click the edit button for text name change.

Form1

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnOpenForm2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 f2 = new Form2(this);
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }

    public string ListBoxValue
    {
        get { return listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
    }
}
```

Form2

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    Form1 f1;

    public Form2(Form1 f1)
    {
        this.f1 = f1;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = this.f1.ListBoxValue;
    }
}
```

Above code works well but after I open `form2` for editng the text, it's not updated the same text in listbox selected item. It's added as a new item in listbox.

Comment: Could you explain your problem more clearly please? You say it "works well" - could you describe the desired behaviour and how the code is deviating from that.

Answer (score 1):

You have nowhere code where you actually change the value of the selected item from the listbox. You have to move the changes back to Form1 and update the selected item of the listbox. You do this through a method `SetSelectedItemValue` for example:

Code of **Form1**:

```
private Form2 _form2;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form2 = new Form2(this);
    _form2.Show();
}

public string ItemValue
{
    get { return listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(); }
}

public void SetSelectedItemValue(string value)
{
    listBox1.Items[listBox1.SelectedIndex] = value;
}
```

Code of **Form2**:

```
public Form2(Form1 form1)
{
    _form1 = form1;
    InitializeComponent();
}

private readonly Form1 _form1;

private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = this._form1.ItemValue;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _form1.SetSelectedItemValue(textBox1.Text);
    Close();
}
```

This code is for demo only, just to show how it works. You'll have to build in validation of user input in the textbox and whether an item from the listbox is selected. Hope this helps!